# how to send data to an email on click without using email clients in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, email

I want to send user data via email without using email clients. I'm following code:  [Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a)

but getting these 4 errors "Invalid ZIP archive:D:\workspace\Form\libs\additionnal.jar ". Please help me out if someone knows.I added external jars in "Android private LIbrairies" folder.  please help me I'm badly stuck in it Thanks.

Comment: The obvious question: is additionnnal.jar a valid jar file?

Comment: @Ravi without using email clients and email intents .. How it will be possible?

Comment: Look for this SO Post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a?lq=1

Comment: @NullByte  I'm following that one but getting no output.. there is no error but I'm getting emails .. why? how would I know my data has been sent ? please do tell??

Comment: What this means " there is no error but I'm getting emails"? it means this code working. for this "how would I know my data has been sent" you can check through your sent mail folder

Comment: @NullByte oh I'm sorry typing mistake!. I checked There's no email regarding that.

Comment: Which email provide you using?

Comment: Use this tutorial well described http://mobiledevtuts.com/android/android-sdk-smtp-email-tutorial/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85291/discussion-between-zaa-ra-and-nullbyte).